# Python 3: How do I determine the re-occuring sub-string/pattern within a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm working on a CheckIO coding problem that involves decoding a message. I Have to find the key from a given encrypted and decrypted message which I've done; pythonpythonpythonpythonp

However, when I use the same key to try and decrypt a message that is longer than that string it fails as I can only start it again from p, and not from y. So, I either need to find a way to find the substring python within the key, or else continue the above key starting from y.

I started off by trying to find each instance of the initial letter of the key and then trying to build a string from there on the assumption that each occurrence of the first letter would be the start of the key.This problem on CheckIO is marked as simple so I'm clearly missing something somewhere.

Here is what I have but it doesn't seem terribly efficient and it relies on the key being a single word repeated. It also falls over if the letter is repeated within the phrase, e.g. checkiocheckioch fails. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
# assumes single word repetition in string

def find_string(strTest):
    a = []
    x = []
    y = []
    for b in range(0, len(strTest)):
        a.append(strTest[b])
    for c in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[c] == a[0]:
            x.append(c)
    for d in range(0, len(x)-1):
        y.append(x[d+1] - x[d])
    if y.count(y[0]) == len(y):
        intWholeStrings = len(strTest) // x[len(x) - 1]
        return find_sub(intWholeStrings, y[0], strTest)
    else:
        return False

def find_sub(intCount, intLen, strTest):
    a1 = strTest[:2]
    for i in range(2, intLen):
        for j in range(1, intCount+1):
            if a1 in strTest[:intLen * j]:
                a1 = a1 + strTest[i]
    return a1

print(find_string('pythonpythonpythonpythonpyth'))
```

Comment: So what are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to find the longest recurring string?

Comment: In my example I need to find what the complete substring is so that I can continue the full string where the part sub-string ended. e.g. string ends in py, so I need to continue it from t rather than starting again from py.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the ***largest substring*** of a given base string I'd use something like this:

```
import re

    def get_largest_substring(string):
        length = 0
        x = 0
        y = 0

        for y in range(len(string)):
            for x in range(len(string)):
                substring = string[y:x]
                if len(list(re.finditer(substring,string))) > 1  and len(substring) > length:
                    match = substring
                    length = len(substring)
        return match

        print get_largest_substring("pythonpythonpythonionpythonionspythonionsd")
```

This also allows for possible alterations in the string and won't throw a wobbly given certain changes that your algorithm would

Comment: Thank you for this. It's kind of where I need to head I think. If I need to continue the string from the next letter in the substring how would I do that? I was doing `pythonpythonppythonpythonp` whereas I need to do `pythonpythonpythonpythonp`. I'm 100% certain I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be :)